# One SQL Server. One SSIS. Two versions of DTExec.exe?

Tags: ssis, license, ssdt, dtexec

Is it possible to install and use the 2012 version of the DTExec.exe on a Server 2008R2/SSIS2008 box without installing SSIS 2012?  All jobs will be called from the command line, no server agent jobs. I see that the [2012 SSDT BI Tools download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843) contains the DTexec.exe tools and it's required binaries. Would that work?

An example...

The path to the existing 2008 DTExec tool on a 2008R2 SQL Server is..

```
\\SQLSERVERNAME2008\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\105\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe
```

Could we drop the 2012 DTExec and binaries from SSDT BI Tools onto that server into this path?

```
\\SQLSERVERNAME2008\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe
```

Will this work?  Do we have to install SSIS 2012? Why?  Why Not?  Any help you can provide will be useful.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

No.

SSD-BI edition is now a free download. That license allows you to *develop* SSIS packages that target a 2012 SQL Server Integration Services machine. That license does not grant you the right to use it for production-like usage.

Furthermore, when you try to run a package from the command line, you're going to be met with an exception stating that ~ this is only for invocation through Visual Studio. The only way to make that go away is by installing the SQL Server Integration Services Service which is part of the 2012/2014 installation media.

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading that [back in SQL Server 2000 DTS executable and binaries were redistributable](http://sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Redistribute-SSIS.aspx). Which at that time you just had to have a CAL license for SQL Server. Microsoft more or less removed that clarity with regards to SSIS when it was first released. However, as noted in the link some [portions of BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337371.aspx) note that SSIS is not redistributable like SQL Server 2000 DTS was since it is a server component of SQL Server now:

> **Install Integration Services**
>
> Although installing BI Development Studio lets you design packages, running packages outside the development environment requires the installation of Integration Services. Subject to the terms of your SQL Server licensing agreement, you may be able to run Setup again to add Integration Services to your installation. Integration Services is now a server component and is not redistributable to client computers in the same manner that the components required for SQL Server 2000 Data Transformation Services (DTS) were redistributable.

Which I would bet if you read the EULA that comes with SSDT-BI and SQL Server it will have verbiage stating in some manner that all components of SQL Server are non-distributable.

I have heard of folks that do just what you have mentioned and I expect are not licensed for that type of setup. Whether you only require SQL Server CAL licenses to cover the SQL Server 2012 SSIS install, I can't say with complete clarity. It is something you will need to ask your software vendor or Microsoft rep.

Comment: Hmmm. Clarity on this issue seems hard to come by!  This seems in no small part to Microsoft making DTExec freely distributable (2005) then a part of SQL Server SSIS (2008) and then once again making it freely distributable as part of via SSDT-BI (2012).  


How about technical feasibility?  Has anyone attempted this?